# D SDL binding with Derelict2 on Windows

Tags: linker, makefile, sdl, d

I have problems compiling a D program that uses SDL using a makefile called from DOS, where SDL is supposed to be wrapped by Derelict. In addition, if I use a pragma inside the test program for linking, it tells me the lib file has error 43, not a valid library file.

How to make it link, and am I using the wrong stack (Visual C/C++) ? I think not because it is looking for lib files.

test program

```
//pragma(lib, "D:\\Development\\SDL-1.2.15\\lib\\x86\\SDL.lib");
import derelict.sdl.sdl;

void main()
{
    DerelictSDL.load();

    // now you can call SDL functions
}
```

makefile

```
DMD = dmd
WINDRES = windres.exe
LDFLAGS = -O2 -s `sdl-config --libs`
DFLAGS =
RM   = rm -f
#OBJS = main.o graphic.o grid.o node.o appicon.opc
SRCS = toh_fractal.d
# graphic.d grid.d node.d appicon.opc
PROG = toh_fractal
DERELICT = D:\\Development\\Derelict2
INCLUDE_DERELICT = $(DERELICT)\\import
LIB_DERELICT = DerelictSDL 
LIB_SDL = SDL
#$(DERELICT)\\lib\\
VERS = 0.1.1

.PHONY: clean distclean
all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(SRCS)
    $(DMD) $(DFLAGS) $(PROG) -I$(INCLUDE_DERELICT) appicon.res -L$(LIB_DERELICT) -L$(LIB_SDL) 

appicon.res: appicon.rc sierpinski.ico
    windres -i appicon.rc -o appicon.res

distclean:
    $(RM) *~ $(OBJS) appicon.opc stdout.txt stderr.txt

clean:
    $(RM) *~ $(OBJS) $(PROG) appicon.opc stdout.txt stderr.txt
```

makefile output

```
C:\D\D_fractals_of_hanoi>make all
dmd  toh_fractal -ID:\\Development\\Derelict2\\import appicon.res -LDerelictSDL  -LSDL
OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.12
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2010  All rights reserved.
http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
OPTLINK : Warning 9: Unknown Option : NOIDERELICTSDLSDL
toh_fractal.obj(toh_fractal)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D8derelict3sdl3sdl12__ModuleInfoZ
toh_fractal.obj(toh_fractal)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined         _D8derelict3sdl3sdl11DerelictSDLC8derelict3sdl3sdl17DerelictSDLLoader
--- errorlevel 2
```

Comment: dmd can't use VC lib files. It needs OMF ones created by dmc or converted with something like objconv.

Comment: objconv doesn't feel able to handle import libraries

Comment: But coffimplib.exe seemed to do something.

Comment: objconv take SDLmain.lib, while coffimplib.exe doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derelict is meant ot be used with dynamic linking. You should put the right .so or .dll in your application directory and Derelict will find it.

Answer (score 0):

Derelict uses the C `dl` lib (`dlopen`, `dlclose`, `dlsym`) to dynamically load the shared library, so you have to use dynamic libraries.